# Mathjax in Github pages

Tags: github, github-pages, mathjax

I have started a new project in Github and as I will need to collaborate with people, I wanted to start a decent documentation. I would like to use Github Pages for this task, but the documentation will need to include many equations, as for instance https://wec-sim.github.io/WEC-Sim/theory.html.

I have read on-line on numerous posts that Mathjax provides a good tool to read equations on browsers and has been linked to Github pages. However, although I tried to follow many different strategies, I have not been able to get my Page to show any equations yet.

You can find my project at https://github.com/enricoande/uuv and the corresponding page at https://enricoande.github.io/uuv/. The page is built from https://github.com/enricoande/uuv/blob/master/docs/README.md.

Initially, I was not able to display equations at all, but could see the text in the Page. Now, I am not even able to see the page. This has happened after adding the file https://github.com/enricoande/uuv/blob/master/docs/_layouts/page.html which reads

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

Is it possible that the reason why I can no longer see my page is that Mathjax is too slow (I have found comments on this regard on-line)? Otherwise, have you got suggestions on what I could do to fix the Page to display the equations?

As you can see I am a beginner with Github pages and html.

Any suggestion is well appreciated as I am now utterly stuck. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the HTML source of your page, you'll notice that it contains nothing but the script tag.

This is expected since [your page template](https://github.com/enricoande/uuv/blob/master/docs/_layouts/page.html) is not actually a template -- for that it would have to contain `{{ content }}` or similar liquid templating tags so that it can pull content from the actual page.

For example, https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/docs/_layouts/page.html has

```
---
layout: default
---

<section class="standalone">
  <div class="grid">

    <div class="unit whole">
      <article>
        <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
        {{ content }}
      </article>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

  </div>
</section>
```

You will then have to create an `index.html` file in your docs folder that starts with

```
---
layout: page
---
```

so that it pulls in the page template (and the script tag).

Try installing jekyll and generating the default site to evaluate good defaults; see [the docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/quickstart/) for more information on that. Usually, a script tag appears in a head, header or footer template.

Comment: Thank you for the help. From your solution it is now clear to me that I definitely have an html problem with my page. If I modify `page.html` as you suggest, the page is displayed again. So, it was clearly my original `page.html` that caused the Page not to be displayed properly (without MathJax I did not have that file and I guess GitHub must have used a template).

Comment: I am getting the hang of it from the Jekyll GitHub directory. However, that is a much more complex project. If I simply want to start with a unique MD file, `README.md`, how can specify to read from it in `page.html` after the title? Is it the `{{content}}` command? Besides, where should I put `<sript....</script>` (note that this is the command to read from MathJax in the post above)? Just before `<article>`? Thanks!

Comment: @Enrico I suspect just using `{{content}}` and adding the script tag should work fin; the MathJax script tag can go either before or after the content, MathJax doesn't mind

Comment: Ok, thank you! I will now try that and hopefully it should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

If I open the referenced JS file at https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML, I see

> console.warn('WARNING: cdn.mathjax.org has been retired. Check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.')

So check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for detailed migration tips.

Example solution

```
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?...">
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! You are right: I did not notice the page had migrated.

Comment: Unluckily, I think I also have a html problem, as @Peter Krautzberger has pointed out.